# Why can't server find an included file

Tags: php, mpdf

Can anyone tell me what is going on here?

```
Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/../../../application/libraries/includes/functions.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /../../../application/libraries/mpdf.php on line 38
```

Specifically, I don't understand the 'include_path'. My take on this is that line 38 of mpdf.php is looking for 'functions.php', but I don't have anything in /application/libraries/includes on my local machine but it still works ok, but fails on the production server.

Thanks in advance,

G.

Comment: Probably this works on your local machine because the `functions.php` is somewhere else in your PHP inclusion path. You need to add it in the directory you yourself rightfully listed...

Comment: Are you sure root directory on localhost and server is the same? Don't think so... Use relative path, without beginning `/`.

Comment: if you are in a Linux platform on live,make sure you call the same file name(i mean the letter-case).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the comments especially Richard, which did indeed point me in the right direction. The file it was looking for was in the mpdf/ directory so I simply copied it to the /includes directory and that fixed the problem. Lesson learned: read the error message very carefully - in this case it contained the answer.

Thanks again,
UnplugNgo.